# Agile Accelerator (GUS) Source Control connector

Tags: managed-package, sourcecontrol

Since this is a managed package I am not able to dig into the code and figure out how stuff works but it appears that the SF Agile Accelerator AKA GUS has links into GIT and a couple of other source control options. Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to the devs on twitter and got a really good answer, https://twitter.com/aDroidman/status/613001785016320000

In short, its a web hook that populates those fields.